# WebStorm does not support `enum` or `readonly` for TypeScript

Tags: typescript, webstorm

WebStorm does not recognize `enum` or `readonly` when using TypeScript.

I tried to read more on TypeScript config files. I am currently using these files: `.eslintignore`, `.eslintrc`, `tsconfig.json` and `tslint.json`.

[image: WebStorm Img 1]

[image: WebStorm Image 2]

Comment: it definitely does support both. What errors do you see namely, what IDE version do you use? some screenshots illustrating the issue would be helpful

Comment: Hello, please see update.

Comment: That's not WebStorm. That's ESLint.

Comment: So how do I allow eslint to support enum and readonly?

Comment: Never used it, but reading the documentation should help, as always: https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring, https://www.npmjs.com/package/@typescript-eslint/parser

Comment: see also https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/eslint.html#ws_eslint_linting_typescript_files_with_eslint

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have ESLint (a JS parser) running on your TS files, which will show errors as TS isn't JS! Try and play around with your IDE settings to use TSLint instead.